# Writing and Reading video without saving in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want to read a video after I write it with `cv2.VideoWriter` without saving the video.

For example:

```
video =  cv2.VideoWriter('using.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 10, size)
```

Now, after writing this `cv2.VideoWriter` object, is it possible to read it like`video.read()`, but since `read()` is a function of `cv2.VideoCapture` and it will throw an error

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'cv2.VideoWriter' object has no attribute 'read'
```

So, is there possible way of reading the `cv2.VideoWriter`?

Comment: You ca create an empty list before you start generating your video, then add frames to it instead of writing them to disk. Then iterate through the frames afterwards to replay them. If your video is of any significant size or duration, you will probably not be able to store the full frames in RAM, so as MJPEG is apparently acceptable quality for you, JPEG-encode the images with `cv2.imencode()` before adding to your list.

Comment: yes, you are right, the accepted answer had suggested just that, apart from the `cv2.imencode` part. The only reason I was using `cv2.VideoCapture` in the first place was because I thought it was the only way to store frames. Lists works without a problem, so thanks for your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to reading frames from the video writer, is to save the frames in a list instead of saving each frame in the the loop. when you finished, you can write them outside the loop and have the save affect as video.read()

```py
video =  cv2.VideoWriter('using.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 10, size)
for frame in frames:
    writer.write(frame)
for frame in frames:
    # do other stuff here
```

detailed example (Notice i changed the fourcc - your example didnt work for me)

```py
import cv2


def cam_test(port: int = 0) -> None:
    frames = []
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(port)
    if not cap.isOpened():  # Check if the web cam is opened correctly
        print("failed to open cam")
    else:
        print('cam opened on port {}'.format(port))

        for i in range(10 ** 10):
            success, cv_frame = cap.read()
            if not success:
                print('failed to capture frame on iter {}'.format(i))
                break
            frames.append(cv_frame)
            cv2.imshow('Input', cv_frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if k == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Now you have the frames at hand

    if len(frames) > 0:
        # if you want to write them
        size = (frames[0].shape[1], frames[0].shape[0])
        video = cv2.VideoWriter(
            filename='using.mp4',
            fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(c1='m', c2='p', c3='4', c4='v'),
            fps=10,
            frameSize=size
        )
        for frame in frames:
            video.write(frame)

        # and to answer your question, you wanted to do video.read() which would have gave you frame by frame
        for frame in frames:
            pass  # each iteration is like video.read() if video.read() was possible

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cam_test()
```

Comment: the idea is good, but can you write a more detailed example so that i can I clearly understand.

Comment: the solution worked, thanks for the edit in the answer!!